# Android Services in Qt Quick (JavaScript)

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm evaluating Qt Quick for cross-platform mobile apps and I'll need background services. I've spent the last couple of hours at the Qt Documentation website trying to find anything concerning implementing a Service via the QML API (JavaScript) without touching C++. Please is this possible?

Comment: Unsure if there ready to use QML Item type for handling the Android Service as long as QML is about UI. Maybe it makes sense to look at this example: https://github.com/bbernhard/qtandroidservices_example

Comment: @AlexanderVX - QML is NOT about UI. It is a declarative language that can be used to define any structure, and it also includes JS support for scripting. Non-GUI usage of QML is possible, there are such libraries, for example qbs.

Comment: @dtech - "It is a JSON-like declarative language for designing user interface–centric applications." From Wikipedia and I am not arguing that potentially we can, say, write user-mode drivers with it.

Comment: If wikipedia told you to jump off a bridge, would you? GUI was the first primary use of QML, but nothing in its design is GUI intrinsic.

Comment: To me "about UI" and "primary use is GUI" is kind of close. That is why I did not point to some principle which totally prevents QML from being used here but to specific QML Item type (not?) available to implement that specific functionality.